# Calculating Short Distanced Traveled IOS

Tags: ios, gps, distance, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm working on a part on my app that requires the user to walk a certain distance in order to continue. It's a relatively short distance 25ft or 30ft. Once the user walks the certain distance they can continue. I have done my research but I'm having trouble finding out how to do this, I came across this tutorial. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Getting_Location_Information_using_the_iOS_7_Core_Location_Framework

I followed it and it works but the distance calculator is not accurate at all. Is there any way that I can calculate 25/30ft accurately with the iPhones GPS? Please let me know because I'm really stuck here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

25 feet are 7.6m

This is a bit to low to detect in many cases.
Change to 10m or 15m.

Another solution is to count steps.
There is an ios API (from Apple)  which can count steps, based on acceleration sensor

Comment: Thank you, it's a shame you can only count steps with the newer generation devices. Thanks for your help really did put me in the right direction.